# Laravel 5.2 multiple orwhere clause

Tags: php, laravel

I have four textboxes I want to get the user information in case found any of four input. I tried below code does not work for me please guide.

```
public function showUser(Request $request) {

         $this->validate($request, [
                'email'     => 'required_without_all:email,phone,name,address',
                'phone'  => 'required_without_all:email,phone,name,address',
                'name'  => 'required_without_all:email,phone,name,address',
                'address'  => 'required_without_all:email,phone,name,address',
            ]);


       $userDetail = User::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('email',  $request->email);
        })->orwhere(function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->orwhere('phone_number',  $request->phone)
                  ->orwhere('name',  $request->name)
                  ->orwhere('address', $request->address);
        })->first();

        return view('admin.user.suggest.show', compact('userDetail'));
    }
```

Also elobrate why this does not work for me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have any result set ?

Comment: @shan result set mean, if you talking about column in db yes It has the value

Comment: No , i meant, r u getting any value in $userDetail , or just wrong result ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting first row value that is in db.

Comment: @Amy Could you please edit the question with `toSql()` from the `$userDetail`?

Comment: So, What really doesn't works for you ?. is that the wrong result. Your query is fine & it should look like this ::  SELECT * FROM user WHERE(`email`='you@domain.com') OR (`phone_number`='123456' OR `name`='your_name' OR `address` = 'your_address') LIMIT 1

Comment: select * from `users` where (`email` = ?) or (`phone_number` = ? or `name` = ? or `address` = ?) this is i'm getting if i remove first()

Comment: Why email is blank can't understand if i do print it looks fine

Comment: One thing more If i remove or where clause it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Current sql result

```
select * from `user` where (`email` = ?) or (`phone_number` = ? or `name` = ? or `address` = ?) LIMIT 1
```

U need

```
select * from `user` where (`email` = ?) and (`phone_number` = ? or `name` = ? or `address` = ?) LIMIT 1
```

try this

```
$userDetail = User::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('email',  $request->email);
    })->orwhere(function ($query) use ($request){
        $query->orwhere('phone_number',  $request->phone)
              ->orwhere('name',  $request->name)
              ->orwhere('address', $request->address);
    })->first();
```

Comment: @Amy Could you give me the mysql output that you want to have and the current one?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `->orWhere` with uppercase "W" ? in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) or Statements have uppercase "W"